# Whats my dbname and dbuser in PuPHPet/vagrant box?

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

I've created a vagrant box with puphpet. In my config.yaml I find this configuration:

```
mariadb:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '10.1'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mariadbnu_1sjud3y9kj91:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        mariadbnd_93b5yjigpuw0:
            name: dbname
            sql: ''
```

Can anybody tell me where dbname and dbuser are defined?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you have to configure it first 
check this.. https://rachelandrew.co.uk/presentations/deploy/puphpet